# dhtmlx schedular addMarkedTimespan

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

```
scheduler.addMarkedTimespan({//block each week end
     days:[5],
      zones: "fullday",
      type:  "",
      css:   "holiday",
      html: "Holiday"});
```

the above code means every friday will be block. But i want to any specific friday will be unblock. it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace days  and zones property into start_date and end_date property.

If you want specific friday will be blocked just call

```
start_date : new Date(2015,23,01),
end_date : new Date(2015,24,01)
```